# How to distribute iOS swift framework without the source code using pods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, ios-library

I have been trying to create a git repo with my framework and trying to distribute it using pods. I have written a podspec which downloads all the dependencies as well as my framework. The pod functions properly. I even imported the framework to the appDelegate of the sample project to test its functionality.
Now when I am using a class of that framework I am getting the following error

> 'MyClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class

I have tried to build the project for both simulator and iPhone, but the result being the same.
Does anyone has insight on this one?

Comment: Is `MyClass` marked `public`?

Comment: @EricD Yes it is.. Also all the public classes implementation is present in the MyFrameworkName-Swift.h file...

Comment: afaik cocoapods is built to show you the source code of your open source dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried a "clean build folder" ? (cmd + alt + shift + k)

Comment: @H4Hugo I have... I have actually tried generating build for iPhone simulator, device as well as a universal build, all of which give me the same error.